# How to make time-dependent code?

Tags: conditionals, datetime

I would like to create a command `\ifafter{year}{month}{day}{yes}{no}` so that if the current date is after `year`/`month`/`day`, the command would produce `yes`, and otherwise produce `no`.

[I came up with a solution, and I wanted to document it as well as see other solutions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Natural generalizations, e.g. a version that compares the current time with `hour` : `minute` : `second`, a version that checks whether `year`/`month`/`day` is further than `x` days in the future (or past), etc., would also be welcomed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The same result can be obtained without any package:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifafter[3]{%
  \ifnum\the\year\two@digits\month\two@digits\day >
     \numexpr#1\two@digits{#2}\two@digits{#3}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

We can also encode the date as "year*10000+month*100+day", so the test can be

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifafter[3]{%
  \ifnum\numexpr\year*10000+\month*100+\day\relax
       >\numexpr#1*10000+#2*100+#3\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Or, with `etoolbox` and `datetime`, without an auxiliary counter:

```
\newcommand{\ifafter}[5]{%
  \ifnumgreater
    {\the\year\twodigit{\the\month}\twodigit{\the\day}}
    {#1\twodigit{#2}\twodigit{#3}}
    {#4}
    {#5}% 
}
```

The relevant thing here is that TeX continues to expand tokens when it is looking for a number. My definitions allow also

```
\ifafter{2012}{1}{16}{Yes, it is after Jan. 16, 2012.}{No, it is not after Jan. 16, 2012.}
```

Your macro would be unsuccessful on Jan. 17, 2012 with

```
\ifafter{2012}{2}{1}{after}{not after}
```

as the comparison would be between 20120117 and 201221. Using `\twodigit` both for today's date and the user input guarantees correct result even when the user is lazy.

And the LaTeX3 version:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\ifafter}{ m m m }
  {
   \int_compare:nTF
     { \year*10000+\month*100+\day > #1*10000+#2*100+#3 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Fantastic! `:)`

Answer (score 12):

You can use the date registers `\year`, `\month` and `\day` which hold the current year, month and day as integers. If you put `\the` in front of them they expand to the number, which is important if you want to concatenate these numbers.

You can use the `\ifnum` primitive to compare two integers. You need however add a `0` if the month or day is lower than 10:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ifafter}[3]{%
    \ifnum#1#2#3<\the\year\ifnum\month<10 0\fi\the\month\ifnum\day<10 0\fi\the\day\space
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ifafter{2012}{01}{16}{After 16th Jan 2012.}{Before 16th Jan 2012.}

\ifafter{2012}{01}{17}{After 17th Jan 2012.}{Before 17th Jan 2012.}

\ifafter{2012}{01}{18}{After 18th Jan 2012.}{Before 18th Jan 2012.}
\end{document}
```

This does not require any package nor e-TeX.

For anything more complex I can recommend the `datenumber` package which allows to calculate the difference in days between two dates. See the `\daydifftoday` example at the back of the package manual.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution I came up with. Compiling the following code today (Jan. 17, 2012),

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{etoolbox,datetime}  
\newcommand{\twodigitday}{\twodigit{\the\day}}
\newcommand{\twodigitmonth}{\twodigit{\the\month}}
\newcounter{mydatenum}
\setcounter{mydatenum}{\the\year\twodigitmonth\twodigitday}
\newcommand{\ifafter}[5]{\ifnumgreater{\arabic{mydatenum}}{#1#2#3}{#4}{#5}}
\begin{document}
\ifafter{2012}{01}{16}{Yes, it is after Jan. 16, 2012.}{No, it is not after Jan. 16, 2012.}
\ifafter{2012}{01}{17}{Yes, it is after Jan. 17, 2012.}{No, it is not after Jan. 17, 2012.}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]